# Using two for loops to define datasets and variables in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataset

I need to access variables from two different data sets in a simple loop (below). (I realize this requires the Negative and Positive vectors to be the same length...luckily, this will always be the case.)

```
Groups<-c("bdiControl","bdi")
Positive<-c("PA","Sad_PA","Amuse_PA","Happy_PA","Disgust_PA")
Negative<-c("NA","Sad_NA","Amuse_NA","Happy_NA","Disgust_NA")

for (g in Groups) {
    for (i in Positive) { 

if (sd(Groups[[g]]$Positive[[i]])<sdthresh | sd(Groups[[g]]$Negative[[i]]])<sdthresh){
cat('Standard deviation too low to run\ ',Positive[[i]],Negative[[i]],'\ comparison')
}
else{
corr<-cor(Groups[[g]]$Positive[[i]],Groups[[g]]$Negative[[i]],use="complete.obs") 
print("The correlation between " Positive[[i]] " and " Negative[[i]] " was " corr "for " Groups[[g]])
}
}
}
```

Other references I have tried include g$i, Groups[g]$Positive[i], g$Positive[[i]], and similar permutations. I think I am spinning my wheels in a rut of problem solving. Help?! :)

Comment: What is the question? (The code as you have it won't run. Is the problem that you need to fix the bugs in it?)

Comment: Clarification: `bdiControl` and `bdi` are two data frames? And each has 10 columns: 5 positive and 5 negative? This would be *much* clearer if you provided reproducible versions of those data frames using `dput(bdiControl)` or just a fraction, like `dput(head(bdiControl))`

Comment: Could you explain the problem from scratch: it's very hard to reverse engineer what you're trying to do. (Something like: "I have two data frames, `bdiControl` and `bdi`, and each has 5 pairs of observations, positive and negative. I need to find the correlation between...")

Comment: I have two data frames (bdi and bdiControl) with the same variables. The code generates errors like "Error in g$i : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". When I hard code the datasets$vars it runs, so I'm fairly sure the error is in these variables.

Comment: You're still not saying what you're trying to do. Are you trying to correlate the same variable between the two data frames, or positive with negative within each data frame? I understand that you're trying to access pairs of variables using strings that describe them- I can tell you how to do that, but I want to make sure I'm telling you the right way.

Comment: Yes, I reduced the code a bit to (I thought!) reduce confusion. Basically, I am collecting correlations between the same variables in two separate data sets that will later (after z-transformation) be compared (using a t-test). I realize there are other ways than subsetting the original data set to achieve this (e.g., restrict data included on the fly), but I have run into similar situations in coding where it actually would be helpful to know how to write the code this way.

Comment: This isn't looking at the same variables in two separate data sets, this looks like it's trying to compare the positive vs negative within the same group (see the line `cor(Groups[[g]]$Positive[[i]],Groups[[g]]$Negative[[i]]`- it's not correct, but it definitely looks like "same group, positive vs negative). Is that not what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were many issues with this code. While it wasn't entirely clear what the code was trying to do (you should ask your question more clearly), I believe this will do what you want:

```
for (group.name in Groups) {
    g <- get(group.name)  # retrieve the actual data
    for (i in 1:length(Positive)) { 
        if (sd(g[[Positive[i]]]) < sdthresh | sd(g[[Negative[i]]]) < sdthresh) {
               cat('Standard deviation too low to run\ ',
                    Positive[[i]], Negative[[i]], '\ comparison')
        }
        else{
            corr<-cor(g[[Positive[i]]], g[[Negative[i]]],use="complete.obs")
            print(paste("The correlation between", Positive[[i]],
                    "and", Negative[[i]], "was", corr, "in", group.name))
        }
    }
}
```

For example, when I created random datasets (always provide a reproducible example!) with:

```
set.seed(1)
bdicontrol = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10))
bdi = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10))
colnames(bdicontrol) <- c(Positive, Negative)
colnames(bdi) <- c(Positive, Negative)
```

The output is:

```
[1] "The correlation between PA and NA was -0.613362711250911 in bdicontrol"
[1] "The correlation between Sad_PA and Sad_NA was 0.321335485805636 in bdicontrol"
[1] "The correlation between Amuse_PA and Amuse_NA was 0.0824438791207575 in bdicontrol"
[1] "The correlation between Happy_PA and Happy_NA was -0.192023690189678 in bdicontrol"
[1] "The correlation between Disgust_PA and Disgust_NA was -0.326390681138363 in bdicontrol"
[1] "The correlation between PA and NA was 0.279863504447769 in bdi"
[1] "The correlation between Sad_PA and Sad_NA was 0.115897422274498 in bdi"
[1] "The correlation between Amuse_PA and Amuse_NA was -0.465274556165398 in bdi"
[1] "The correlation between Happy_PA and Happy_NA was 0.268076939911701 in bdi"
[1] "The correlation between Disgust_PA and Disgust_NA was 0.573745174454954 in bdi"
```

Comment: I definitely would never have thought to notate/retrieve the data this way. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: I err on the side of not writing a novel in these questions initially...sorry it took a bit of sleuthing.

Comment: You should write as much as you have to to make it clear (you're not doing any favors otherwise!) By the way, if this answered your question, don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)